# After upgrading, the autoloader is not working

Tags: 8, composer

Recently, I updated from 8.1.8 to 8.1.10 (via `composer update`). In my local environment (running scotchbox, PHP 5.6.14), it runs fine. When deployed to the staging server (running CentOS 6.7, PHP 5.5.17), the site returns a 500 and writes the following to error_log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Site\Settings' not found in /home/[site]/public_html/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php on line 964

I copied basically everything except the /sites/ directory, so I don't think I'm missing anything.

I tried restarting httpd to no avail.

It seems like a problem with the autoloader and possibly due to the PHP version mismatch. There are many layers between autoload.php and the DrupalKernel.php bootstrap process. I'm at a loss as to what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to restart apache?

Comment: I did, question updated to include that info--thanks.

Comment: @pjbeardsley I have same issue and updated my php version 5.5 to 5.6 and it works. As 5.6 considered last stable release of PHP. I hope it works

Comment: Did your composer update updated any vendors ?

Comment: try composer install .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the changes that composer made to your local environment weren't carried over. Without knowing any of the details of what might be different, you'll have to do some introspection. You can test the autoloader in both your dev/staging environment to tease out what's occurring differently in each environment.

There a few things you can do to test the autoloader:

- Within **index.php** you can use the statement `var_dump($autoloader)` to dump the autoloader; it should have a `classMap` property which should have a keyed array that maps classes to PHP files. It should include a value for `Drupal\Core\Site\Settings`.
- Within **vendor/composer/autoload_real.php** is the logic that registers the autoloader and includes other **autoload_*.php** used to build the autoloader object. You can various `var_dump()` statements to follow the path of execution to make sure the autoloader is being built correctly.
- Within **vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php** you use the `var_dump($class)` statement in the `ClassLoader::loadClass($class)` method to have PHP spit out classes as the autoloader is including them.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem changing file permissions.
Try changing group ownership of files to "www-data" recursively both in vendor and web folder.

```
chown -R $USER:www-data vendor web
```

CentOS server should use "apache" instead of "www-data"

```
chown -R $USER:apache vendor web
```